# Use an AEM component from another site

Tags: aem

I have an AEM instance which serves multiple sites. One site has a component in use. I want to use this component on another site. I don't want to copy and paste the component files over to the second site and split the codebase like that. Does anyone know a way to use this component on another site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have two webistes `site1` and `site2`. Components for `site1` would be in component group `Group1` and components for `site2` would be in component group `Group2`.

## Using component groups (quickest and dirtiest)

All you would need to do is add the Group2 component group to the site1 component you want to use.

## [Using policies](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/forms/using/admin-help/creating-policies.html) (less quick and dirty)

In your page templates for `site2`, define a policy that allows the authors to use components from component group `Group2` but also any chose components from `Group1`

## [Using inheritence](https://helpx.adobe.com/lu_en/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/components-basics.html#ComponentHierarchyandInheritance) (sexy)

As [Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6261635/oliver-gebert) mentioned, extract the shared components and put them in a third site (eg: `sitecore`, `siteshare` or something similar). This website is for organizing your components, not for adding and publishing content.

Then in `site1` and `site2`, create components that simply reference those in `sitecore` using the `sling:resourceSuperType` property. Your `site1` and `site2` components will inherit all the the properties and edit dialogs of the referenced components.

If you want to override the `cq:dialog` or `CSS` of your inherited components you can do that too, to give each site a slightly different look-and-feel or behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can use each component on any site usually. There are several ways to organize your dependencies if you are also having several projects (or several folders in /apps).

Make sure to make use of inheritance (resourcecSuperType) and wrapper components if you are planning to do some project specific changes to some of the reused components. 
In order to have a clean dependency hierarchy it might also be useful to extract  components that are used in more than one project to a "base" or "foundation" project.

Have a lookt at [wcm core](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components) and [we-retail](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail). We-retail is reusing the wcm core components.

HTH.